# What's the reason for the occurrence of Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-programming, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I use C language, and apply Dynamic Programming to solve the [Travelling salesman problem](https://zerojudge.tw/ShowProblem?problemid=c178). There is such a problem on ZeroJudge, An Online Judge System For Beginners, but I get Segmentation fault (core dumped) on the 13th, 14th, and 15th test cases. I have checked my code, but I can’t find the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>
#define min(a, b)(a > b ? b : a)
void travel();
int **map,**dp,n;
main()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    map = (int **)calloc(n, sizeof(int *));
    dp = (int **)calloc(n, sizeof(int *));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        map[i] = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        dp[i] = (int *)calloc((1 << (n - 1)), sizeof(int));
    }
    int distance;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &distance);
            map[i][j] = distance;
        }
        dp[i][0] = map[i][0];
    }
    travel();
    printf("%d\n", dp[0][(1 << (n - 1)) - 1]);
    free(map);
    free(dp);
}
void travel()
{
    for(int j = 1 ; j < 1 << (n - 1) ; j++) 
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)   
        {
            dp[i][j] = INT_MAX;
            if(j >> (i - 1) & 1)  
            {
                continue;
            }
            for(int k = 1 ; k < n ; k++)
            {
                if(!(j >> (k - 1) & 1))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], map[i][k] + dp[k][j ^ (1 << (k - 1))]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Content

```
Given a set of cities and the distances between each pair of cities, find the shortest distance sum of a tour that starts from a city, visits all the cities without repetition, and returns to the starting city.
For example, the visiting order is 1-2-3-4-1. The distance sum is 10 + 25 + 30 + 15 = 80.
```

Input Description

```
There is only one set of test data. The first line of each set has an integer N, indicating that there are N cities. Then there will be N lines, each line has N non-negative integers Di,j indicating the distance from node i to node j. If Di,j = 0, it is considered that there is no edge.
You can assume that each edge may be unidirectional, and guarantee that there is at least one TSP path.
* 3 < N ≤ 35
* 0 distance between any pair of cities ≤ 10000
```

Output Description

```
Output a line of minimum distance sum.
```

Example input #1

```
4
0 10 15 20
10 0 35 25
15 35 0 30
20 25 30 0
```

Example Output #1

```
80
```

Comment: OT: Please don't use so-called "competition" or "judge" sites to learn the basics of C, or any programming language. That's just not their purpose, no matter what you have been told. If you're serious then invest in some good books, and take classes. Your code unfortunately showcases some of the bad habits that are being "taught" on such sites. A good class would also teach you about how to *debug* your programs, which is required knowledge for any programmer.

Comment: you should add the test data with which your program fails

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement says “3 < N ≤ 35”. The program uses `1 << (n - 1)` in several places, where `n` contains the value of N. This shifts the `int` value 1 by as much as 34 bits. However, `int` is commonly 32 bits in current C implementations, so shifting by more than 30 bits overflows, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Further, the program attempts to allocate space for an array of `1 << (n - 1)` `int` elements, in `calloc((1 << (n - 1)), sizeof(int))`. This may fail due to being too large a request, especially since it is repeated N times. Or the overflow in `1 << (n - 1)` may result in insufficient memory being requested.

You need a new algorithm that does not attempt to use so much memory.